# 'undefined' output in console, using console.log()

Tags: javascript, console

I am new to JavaScript, try to learn how to read a function, it would be great if someone could look at this code and tell me why I am getting 'undefined' output here:

```
const myArray = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
```

```
function arryIncludesMain(arr, item) {
  return arr.includes(item);
}

function arryIncludesAlt(arr, item) {
  if (arr.includes(item)) {
    console.log("true");
  } else {
    console.log("false");
  }
}

console.log(myArray.includes(8))

console.log("-----------------------------------------------");

console.log("Main function output:");
console.log(arryIncludesMain(myArray, 3));
console.log(arryIncludesMain(myArray, 6));
console.log("-----------------------------------------------");

console.log("Alt function output:");
console.log(arryIncludesAlt(myArray, 3));
console.log(arryIncludesAlt(myArray, 6));
```

And here is the console output:

```
false
-----------------------------------------------
Main function output:
true
false
-----------------------------------------------
Alt function output:
true
undefined
false
undefined
```

What is the difference between Main and Alt approach that I am getting 'undefined' output in console? what this 'undefined' refer to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions [`return`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return):

In JavaScript, when a function does not have a `return` statement or when it reaches the end of the function without returning a value, it implicitly returns `undefined`.

`arryIncludesAlt()` does not have a `return` statement, and instead, it uses `console.log` to print a string (`true` or `false`) to the console.

Comment: Thanks! but shouldn't it crash instead of showing 'undefined'. like Java?

Comment: In javascript you don't declare the return value. So the compiler doesn't really know what should be returned.

Comment: Thanks! now I understand, why I am getting this result. :)

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're getting undefined, is because your arrayIncludesAlt function is not returning anything, instead it's a 'void' method that logs
the result. So you shouldn't call `console.log` on this method.

Instead of doing:

```
console.log(arryIncludesAlt(myArray, 3)); // logs undefined
console.log(arryIncludesAlt(myArray, 6)); // logs undefined
```

You should be doing:

```
arryIncludesAlt(myArray, 3) // will do console.log while calling this function
arryIncludesAlt(myArray, 6) // will do console.log while calling this function
```

As inside your `arryIncludesAlt` function you're already logging the result.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is "return" statement. It makes function to have a result.

The alternate way is:

```
function arryIncludesAlt(arr, item) {
  if (arr.includes(item)) {
    console.log("true");
  } else {
    console.log("false");
  }
  return arr.includes(item);
}
```